# Will an HTML 5 video file be downloaded twice?

Tags: html, html5-video

If I have two video tags in a webpage with the same file reference, will it downloaded twice or will it use the same downloaded file?
Please indicate if the behavior differs per browser.

Comment: Why don't you test it and see?  You can use the browser's built-in tools to see.

Comment: I would if I knew how to tell. You could post with an answer on how to test this.

Comment: I think it's `F12` or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I` in most browsers to open the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

When I run a page test for Chrome, it appears to download the same video file each time that video is referenced. I'm using HTML5 `<video>` tags.